# How to clear static IP configuration and start DHCP

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm using a sketch like this:

```
WiFi.config(IP, Gate, Subnet);
WiFi.begin (ssid, pass);

//-- somewhere below I want to drop the static IP configuration and obtain IP with DHCP.

WiFi.disconnect ();
WiFi.begin (ssid, pass). //ssid and pass are the same as above.
```

But IP is not changing. It seems that WiFi hasn't been reconnected. How to drop static IP configuration without restart? I'm using nodemcu v3 with esp8266 -12e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. There is a DHCP issue at Arduino firmware. When I did checked from the [WiFiSTA](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4897e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp) firmware implementation, I saw that staticIP flag get set once when you call config() function and never get cleared. This flag guards the DHCP start/stop operations. 
So, here is a solution for you. Just add the ESP SDK header to your code like:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "user_interface.h"
}
```

Now you are able to call dhcp start function from firmware which was previously blocking by the flag. But, notice that you have to call it after `WiFi.begin()` with some delay. Use the code block below:

```
WiFi.disconnect(true);
delay(1000);
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
(void)wifi_station_dhcpc_start();
```

Comment: You _can_ reset static without resorting to the C Espressif SDK calls, although it's not particularly obvious. You must call WiFi.config(0, 0, 0); to reset the static configuration back to DHCP. I am not sure if this was introduced in a later version than the current release (2.3.0), but, it's working in the newest Git.

Comment: 0,0,0 config is not also too obvious, both way need to check implementation to get notation. In lua firmware there is a dhcp starter method. Maybe it is also be introduced in later releases for arduino. Yes, as you said zero check is included in latest and 2.30.

Comment: Using WiFi.config(0, 0, 0); i get error: conversion from 'int' to 'IPAddress' is ambiguous

WiFi.config(0, 0, 0);

Comment: You can use the method I've explained above.

Comment: Yes it work well, but WiFi.config(0, 0, 0) a little bit easy.

Comment: OK. So it looks like a type error. Maybe you can pass like that : `IPAddress addr(0, 0, 0, 0);` for each IP address. So : `WiFi.config(addr, addr, addr);`

Comment: I tried IPAddress addr(0, 0, 0, 0) at first, but it didn't help too. Only (void)wifi_station_dhcpc_start() do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This should really be a comment to the accepted answer but my reputation is not high enough... Anyways, as noted in that answer there is a built in option for resetting the staticIP flag, but the trick to making it work is that the arguments need to be unsigned. I.e. `WiFi.config(0u, 0u, 0u);`. Should the unsigned part be omitted, you get the "conversion from 'int' to 'IPAddress' is ambiguous" error mentioned in the accepted answer's comments.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp) for the Arduino firmware's station class one can see that `WiFi.config(0u, 0u, 0u);` actually changes a protected flag in addition to executing `wifi_station_dhcpc_start()`, so I would say that using `WiFi.config(0u, 0u, 0u);` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to put the exact code you need as an edit to Anders response but the edit got rejected for some reason. Gotta love stack overflow sometimes. I tried for some time to get this working and it doesn't work if you just call `WiFi.config(0u, 0u, 0u);`. Lots of other combinations that I thought would work didn't. Credit goes to both Anders and Cagdas's as this is just their 2 answers combined. This is the exact code you need to get it working. Apologies if I'm breaking another of the many stack overflow rules :/

```
WiFi.disconnect(true);
delay(1000);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
WiFi.config(0U, 0U, 0U);
```

Answer (score 0):

got same problem w/ ESP12E
was solved using this command with AT firmware

```
AT+RESTORE
```

also googled variants (not tested) for other environment:
NodeMCU - `node.restore()`, Eclipse example (?) - `system_restore()`